# IShockwaveFlash and Privacy: Allow & Remember + context menu

Tags: c++, flash

Help me please to understand:

IShockwaveFlash and cointerfaces have not any way to

1) programmicaly allow use camera and remember choice
2) disable context menu

?

Is it possible to do it with NSAPI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The point of security is, well, security. It would be pretty awful if any program out there could gain access to users' local hardware and peripherals and do whatever they please with them. So, no, you cannot override or disable Flash's security dialogs. Adobe's site has a lot of documentation on this.